# Will a rotating body gain linear acceleration in water?

Tags: drag, angular-velocity, buoyancy

If a ball is floating in water and it has some angular velocity, will it gain some linear acceleration from the drag on it as it rotates?

**Edit**:

[image: Ball in water]

This is how I pictured it. I guess my reasoning is somewhat like a tyre trying to drive in mud?

I should probably ask as well, if this DOES happen, what is this force called? Equations would be cool too.

**Edit 2**:

OK so this seems to be a pretty definitive yes on the linear acceleration front. But how can I *calculate* this acceleration?

Just so no one is put off answering, this isn't homework. It's just something I'm trying to simulate for a game I'm writing.

Comment: How do you envision the ball spinning? Is its axis parallel to the surface of the water? Perpendicular?

Comment: I meant parallel to the surface. Edited to try and explain better.

Comment: Yes, it'll gain linear acceleration. Tires slip in mud because there's heavy weight to accelerate.

Comment: As Sachin noted, the picture is basically the same as what a car does when its wheels spin and push against the ground. The ball will thus move forward.

Comment: It is a little complicated because the horizontal friction force depends not only on the angular speed, but also on the horizontal speed.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try to apply Newtonian mechanics to this problem.

Since the ball is initially at rest, determining the resulting direction of motion, if any, boils down to determining the direction of the net force on the ball as it spins.

If the direction of the net force isn't obvious (like it might not be here), try teasing out some force by focusing on a different aspect of the motion of the ball: *What will happen to the rotation of the ball?* I suspect it will slow down due to its interaction with the water.

Next, draw several arrows along the bottom surface of the ball that represent the force exerted by the water that would cause the ball to slow down. To keep things simple, let's only focus on the tangental component of the force by the water. (The normal component is responsible for buoyancy; so let's ignore this and focus on any left-right motion as depicted in your diagram.)

Now take a look at the net effect of all of your little force arrows. Is there a preferred direction that they all tend to point in? Answering this question is equivalent to answering what direction the net force on the ball is as it is spinning but initially not translating.

Note that there are some assumptions in the above argument that are glossed over; motionless fluid (initially), no fluid going over on top of the ball, etc.

Comment: I imagine there are little drag force arrows pushing clockwise on the ball, slowing its rotation, so yes they have a preferred direction. But does all that force go into slowing the ball's _rotation_ or does some of it go into accelerating the ball?

Comment: A given force can both slow rotation (provide torque) and provide linear acceleration; a force's effect is not diminished by doing both.